# How to get the total number of tables in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

Is there any way by which I can get the total number of tables in a Postgresql database? The postgresql version I'm using is PostgreSQL 8.4.14.

Comment: To explore what's going on in only one database I usually use `\d`. With this you can list the total number of tables, views and the sequences also.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
select count(*)
from information_schema.tables;
```

Or if you want to find the number of tables only for a specific schema:

```
select count(*)
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'public';
```

Comment: What if we want to count the number of the tables ? I know we can see the number but i want to use this number in a sql statement ?

Comment: Use `where table_type = 'BASE TABLE'` to exclude Views and Temporary Tables from the results.

Answer (score 21):

Just try to search in pg_stat... tables or information_schema you can find there very useful informations about your database.
Example:

```
select * from  pg_stat_user_tables ;
select count(*) from  pg_stat_user_tables ; 
select * from  pg_stat_all_tables ;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get just the number of tables (without views) then:

```
select count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
```

Or you can also filter by schema name by adding the where condition like:

```
table_schema = 'public'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it'w work for me

```
select t.table_catalog,  t.table_schema, t.table_name  from information_schema.tables t where  t.table_catalog = 'database_name';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

```
select Count(*) from sys.tables
```

Comment: This should work for SQL Server, right? Not PostgreSQL.