# finding the count of all table rows in a schema in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I used the following command to obtain the count of each table rows in a schema in oracle 11g. To do the same in postgres what changes should be made? D6 is the schema name

Query:

```
select
table_name,
to_number(
   extractvalue(
      xmltype(
         dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) D6 from '||table_name))
,'/ROWSET/ROW/D6')) count
from user_tables;


Error:

ERROR:  relation "user_tables" does not exist
LINE 8: from user_tables;
             ^


********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "user_tables" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 163
```

The following error is displayed. What changes shall be made?

Comment: possible solution `postgresql` (http://stackoverflow.com/q/13931494/2749470)

Comment: @Bhargav I want the number of rows in each table in the schema .this query returns the number of tables in a schema Table_name:  User_history Count:415 etc..

Comment: `SELECT schemaname,relname,n_live_tup 
  FROM pg_stat_user_tables 
  ORDER BY n_live_tup DESC;`

Comment: `n_live_tup` is an estimate. That might or might not matter.

Comment: @Reenu, this seems to be the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/2596670 - I hope this is helpful to you.   Good luck.

Comment: yes thank you @David found the same answer some time back.. thanks for spending your time :)

Comment: @ReenuRahman I didn't really spend any time on it.  I just wish I had seen your question when you first posted it, instead of a month too late.